# Getting application data using SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, sharedpreferences

I need to extract the application data using `SharedPreferences` in Xamarin.Android.

Here is what I have tried in android.

```
public static void SetAuthentication(bool authenticationValue)
    {
        var localSettings = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences ("Hello", FileCreationMode.Private);
        localSettings.Edit ().PutBoolean ("ValidUser", authenticationValue).Commit ();

    }

    public static bool GetAuthentication()
    {
        var retValue = false;
        object value;
        var localSettings = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences ("Hello", FileCreationMode.Private);
        localSettings.GetBoolean ("ValidUser", out value);
    }
```

But somehow I feel this is not the right approach. 
Any guidance is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What makes you feel this is the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

On the Android platform, preferences are stored in a text file in the private folders of the Android application - there are 2 ways to access these `SharedPreferences` data files.

You can either use the "default" file for the application, or you can use a named file, using any name you want.

This second approach is what you have chosen to do by calling `GetSharedPreferences` with a filename.

---

I would suggest to just use the "default" preferences. This way has some advantages:

- the code is simpler
- the preferences can be accessed more easily in a `PreferenceActivity` later on

To do this, create your `ISharedPreferences` instance using:

```
ISharedPreferences localSettings = 
        PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
```

Once you have your "default" shared preferences in this manner, the rest of your code stays the same.

---

For more info, check out related questions:

- [How do I use SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android)
- [save android app string value after close xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080454/save-android-app-string-value-after-close-xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Richard so just to be clear and complete I would do like this:

```
public static void SetAuthentication(Context ctx, bool authenticationValue)
{
    ISharedPreferences pref = ctx.GetSharedPreferences("your_app_preferences", FileCreationMode.Private);
    ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();
    edit.PutBoolean("ValidUser", authenticationValue);
    return edit.Commit();
}

public static bool GetAuthentication(Context ctx)
{
    ISharedPreferences pref = ctx.GetSharedPreferences("your_app_preferences", FileCreationMode.Private);
    return pref.GetBoolean("ValidUser"), null);
}
```

I hope this will make you feel happier.