# save android app string value after close xamarin

Tags: c#, android, save, xamarin

There is a way to save string value after the app is closed and re open?

I thinking something like `Sqlite` but i want to know if there is something easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use shared preferences. shared preferences is a mechanism for saving key value pair of data like the string you have!

use this youtube playlist to learn how to use shared preferences. http://goo.gl/DAnQqr

Comment: Can I get an example ?

Comment: i added the link. watch videos.

Comment: Sadly that video is not very informative, and it focuses on Java, rather than C# as used by Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this for a small amount of settings is to use Android's Shared Preferences functionality. It is simpler to code than implementing a full SQLite database.

In Android, it is called `SharedPreferences`. You can use that to find many Android java examples which you can port across to Xamarin.

In **Xamarin.Android** C#, that same functionality comes for the interface `ISharedPreferences`, which maps to the SharedPreferences java class.

---

For example, to save your string using C#, you could write something like:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
prefs.Edit ().PutString ("key_for_my_string_value", mString).Commit ();
```

To retrieve it again, you could write something like:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
mString= prefs.GetString ("key_for_my_string_value");
```

---

More info on `ISharedPreferences` in my post here:

- [How do I use SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668566/383414)